# how to get index of element in array after a sum equals some number of previous elements

Tags: javascript

Sum of elements `const sum = 4;`

I want to check all the elements from zero index and sum until elements sum equals `4` and get the immediate index (next index where the sum ends with an element)

for eg a sample of array's::

```
const sampleArr1 = [1,2,1,4,...]
```

here the exp o/p is index of `4` which is `3`

```
const sampleArr2 = [1,3,7,...]
```

here the exp o/p is index of `7` which is `2`

```
const sampleArr3 = [4,10,...]
```

here the exp o/p is index of `10` which is `1`

I have got no clue on how could I do this , any help is appreciated

Comment: What happens if you never arrive at the sum of *exactly* 4? E.g. `[1, 2, 5, ...]` or `[5, 7, ...]`?

Comment: was a good Question , immediate index if sum is greater than 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let sum = 0;
let immediateIndex = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
    if(sum === 4) {
        immediateIndex = i + 1;
        break;
    }
}
```